# Way to target passenger workers directly via thrift

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger, thrift, thrift-protocol

I am trying to have my applications talk with eachother using thrift. All of the applications run in the same network, and all are ruby applications ran with Nginx and Phusion Passenger. I have no problems using thrift to communicate between apps with Thrift::HTTPClientTransport, but this involves exposing an HTTP URL on the receiving application. I have made a rack middleware that takes requests to this path, invokes the called method and responds via thrift.

My question is how can I bypass the need for middleware and thift HTTP transport when running passenger. I have thought of a couple ideas involving making my own proxy server that registers passenger workers as they become available and assigning ports on those works so clients using thrift could invoke methods directly via Thrift::BufferedTransport or Thrift::FramedTransport. I have a feeling that there must be a way to get around the need for a custom proxy service.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Not quite. I settled for using HTTP transport using https://github.com/deees/thrift-rack-middleware on the service I was communicating with. I still use the compressed binary transport with thrift. It is quick enough for now, but socket connections would still be ideal. I was going to write a manager application that managed both sockets and HAProxy's config on the fly, but I didn't have the time to build it. Jim, if you find something else, please let me know.

Comment: Will do Sean. Thanks for the info.